# What is the bank need to get the message?

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

In Number theory 
$p=37, q= 43$, $\phi(pq)= 36 \cdot 42$, $e=5$
$d=?$

What does the bank need to get the message? 
I don't understand this problem. Can any one help me please?

Comment: In plain English, the question "What is the bank need to get the message?" is ill-formed and doesn't make much sense.

Comment: related to RSA Public Key Cryptosystem ?

Comment: I understand that, but the question is still meaningless.

Comment: Ramu, a friendly suggestion from you friendly community moderator. You may benefit from spending a couple of days familiarizing yourself with the site culture. You will quickly learn what is expected from the askers. What context they should provide et cetera. Your question is in dire need of editing. What has the bank got to do with any of this? Ok, many of us can guess that this is an RSA exercise. But the people who can get that far also know that you have been given examples with other numbers - and an algorithm for doing this.

Comment: (cont'd) Therefore a meaningful question would be for you to show how far you can follow that algorithm, and pinpoint the step at which you get confused. As it is written, your question has the air of trying to just get somebody to do your homework for you without you learning anything. This presses people's buttons here. For if you came here expecting a solution, then, I'm afraid, you may deserve the negative attention the current version of your question is getting.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple RSA problem: $d$ is the inverse of $e$ modulo $\phi(n)$, where $n = pq$

So apply the extended Euclidean algorithm ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)) to $e$ and $\phi(n)$.

You get integers $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $ke + l\phi(n) = 1$.

Then $k$ is easily seen to be the required inverse, i.e. $d$ (just take the previous equation modulo $\phi(n)$ where the right term vanishes).

Comment: @ henno..thanks  ..but can u solve this for d

Comment: sorry i am totally confusing and stuck can you help me

Comment: @ramu Apply the extended Euclidean algorithm. You should know it.

Comment: ax+by=gcd(a,b) right

Comment: so what is the final answer

Comment: @ramu not going to say. Do some work yourself?

Comment: @ramu Then you shouldn't be doing the exam maybe? It seems some number theory knowledge is required.

Comment: @ramu type "inverse of 5 modulo (36*42)" in www.wolframalpha.com, for easy answers.